# $E,F$ be closed subsets of $\Bbb{R}^2$ such that $d(E,F)=0$. Then does $d(h(E),h(F))=0$ where $h:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$ is a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

WLOG we can assume $E\cap F=\emptyset$.

As $d(E,F)=\text{inf}\{d(e,f):\ e\in E, f\in F\}=0$, we have a seq $(e_n)$ in $E$ and a seq $(f_n)$ in $F$ such that $d(e_n,f_n)\to 0$ i.e. $(e_n),(f_n)$ are equivalent. As $E\cap F=\emptyset $ and $E,F$ are closed, none of $e_n,f_n$ converges.

But we may not have $d(h(e_n),h(f_n))\to 0$, we will have this when $h$ is uniformly continuous. I think the statement may not be true. But can anyone provide a counter example? Possibly a non uniformly continuous homeomorphism.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: How is it that without loss of generality, we may assume $E \cap F = \emptyset$? I think since $E$ and $F$ are closed, $d \left( E, F \right) = 0$ happens exactly when $E \cap F \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh We can have disjoint closed sets with distance $0$ between them.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, yes! I understand it now.

Comment: What about $E = \Bbb{N}$, $F = \{n + 1/n:n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ and $h(x)=x^3$?

Comment: @Aniruddha if $x\in E\cap F$, then $h(x)\in h(E)\cap h(F)$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Yeah I also think of the same thing. For $\Bbb{R}^2$, take $E=\{(n,0):\ n\in\Bbb{N}\}$, $F=\{(n+1/n,0):\ n\in \Bbb{N}\}$ and $h(x,y)=(x^3,y)$

Answer (score 1):

As $\mathbb{R}^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{D}^2:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\|(x,y)\|<1\}$, it suffices to prove the result for $\mathbb{D}^2$. Now, let $A=\{1-\frac{1}{2n}\}_{n\ge 1}$; $B=\{1-\frac 1{2n+1}\}_{n\ge 1}$.
Let $f$ be any continuous function $[0,1)\to [0,\pi]$ such that $f(0)=0;f(1-\frac 1{2n+1})=\frac\pi2$, $f(1-\frac 1{2n})=0$ and define $h((x,y))=\exp(i f(\|(x,y)\|))(x,y)$. It is easy to see that $h$ is a homeomorphism since $h^{-1}((x,y))=\exp(-if(\|(x,y)\|))(x,y)$ is continuous. However, $h(B)=\exp(i\pi /2)B$; $h(A)=A$ and $d(A,B)>0$.

It should not be hard to modify the construction to get a diffeomorphism with the same properties